# Changing variable in LINQ select

Tags: c#, linq

I'm converting one list to another.
Additionally to data from first list I want to have position added. To do this I created following code:

```
class A
{
    ...
}

class B
{
    ...
    public int Position { get; set; }
}

List<A> listA = ...;
int pos = 1;
List<B> listB = listA.Where(...).Take(...).Select(
    a => new B { ..., Position = pos++ }).ToList();
```

It this working, but should it and will it always work?
Is it safe to use such variable like `pos` in my code and change its value inside LINQ's `Select`?

Comment: _Technically_, in this usage, it's "safe", but generally speaking, best practices dictate that LINQ queries should not have side effects; they should be treated like queries. Minor alterations to this might make it unsafe; say you don't evaluate the query with the `ToList` at the end and keep the `Select` deferred. If you check `pos` before executing the query, `pos` will still be `1`. Or if you evaluate the deferred query more than once, it will continue to increment past what you would normally expect. So favour dcastro's overload, and if you _must_ do something like this, do so _carefully_.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need `pos`. [`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869%28v=vs.100%29.ASPX) has an overload that takes a `Func<T, int, TResult>` as an argument, instead of `Func<T, TResult>`, where the int is the index of the element `T`.

```
listA.Select(
               (a, index) => new B { ..., Position = index}
            ).ToList();
```

---

> Is it safe to use such variable like pos in my code and change its value inside LINQ's Select

In your concrete case, it is safe, mainly because you realize the list immediately (using `ToList`).

Generally, I'd advise against this. Here's why:

```
var collection = listA.Where(...).Take(...).Select(
    a => new B { ..., Position = pos++ });

foreach(var item in collection)
    Console.WriteLine(item.Position); //prints 0,1,2

foreach(var item in collection)
    Console.WriteLine(item.Position); //prints 3,4,5
```

LINQ is stateless. It's supposed to be *pure*, as in, for the same input, you should *always* get the same output. By making the lambda dependent on a mutable variable, you're giving up this very important property.

Comment: Thanks, it solves my current problem, but it doesn't answer my question.